Problem with not finding the player on the path
When the script tries to find out information on the path "game:GetService(“Workspace”).NameValue.Value".
it recognizes it, but if this information is used in the path "game.Players.PlayerName.Settings.Data.Ability.Value" then roblox gives the error “PlayerName is not a valid member of Players ‘Players’” can you help me how to fix this error?
Script:
local Library = loadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Robojini/Tuturial_UI_Library/main/UI_Template_1"))()
local Window = Library.CreateLib("Player infomation", "RJTheme3")

local PlayerName = game:GetService("Workspace").NameValue.Value

local Tab = Window:NewTab("Stand")
local Section = Tab:NewSection("")

local stand = game.Players.PlayerName.Settings.Data.Ability.Value
Section:NewLabel(stand)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local Tab = Window:NewTab("Cash")
local Section = Tab:NewSection("")

local cash = game.Players.PlayerName.Settings.Data.Cash.Value
Section:NewLabel(cash)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local Tab = Window:NewTab("Stand in storage")
local Section = Tab:NewSection("")

local StandInStorage1 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Ability Storage"].Ability_Slot1.Value
local StandInStorage2 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Ability Storage"].Ability_Slot2.Value
local StandInStorage3 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Ability Storage"].Ability_Slot3.Value
local StandInStorage4 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Ability Storage"].Ability_Slot4.Value
local StandInStorage5 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Ability Storage"].Ability_Slot5.Value
local StandInStorage6 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Ability Storage"].Ability_Slot6.Value
Section:NewLabel(StandInStorage1)
Section:NewLabel(StandInStorage2)
Section:NewLabel(StandInStorage3)
Section:NewLabel(StandInStorage4)
Section:NewLabel(StandInStorage5)
Section:NewLabel(StandInStorage6)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local Tab = Window:NewTab("Item in storage")
local Section = Tab:NewSection("")

local ItemInStorage1 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Item Storage"].Item_Slot1.Value
local ItemInStorage2 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Item Storage"].Item_Slot2.Value
local ItemInStorage3 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Item Storage"].Item_Slot3.Value
local ItemInStorage4 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Item Storage"].Item_Slot4.Value
local ItemInStorage5 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Item Storage"].Item_Slot5.Value
local ItemInStorage6 = game.Players.PlayerName.Data["Item Storage"].Item_Slot6.Value
Section:NewLabel(ItemInStorage1)
Section:NewLabel(ItemInStorage2)
Section:NewLabel(ItemInStorage3)
Section:NewLabel(ItemInStorage4)
Section:NewLabel(ItemInStorage5)
Section:NewLabel(ItemInStorage6)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local Tab = Window:NewTab("Settings")
local Section = Tab:NewSection("")

local Camera_Shake = game.Players.PlayerName.Settings["Camera Shake"].Value
local CameraShake = game.Players.PlayerName.Settings.CameraShake.Value
local LowGraphics = game.Players.PlayerName.Settings["Low Graphics"].Value
local Music = game.Players.PlayerName.Settings.Music.Value
Section:NewLabel(Camera_Shake)
Section:NewLabel(CameraShake)
Section:NewLabel(LowGraphics)
Section:NewLabel(Music)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local Tab = Window:NewTab("Leaderstats")
local Section = Tab:NewSection("")

local leaderstats = game.Players.PlayerName.leaderstats["Total Kill"].Value
Section:NewLabel(leaderstats)

Here's what StringValue looks like:

I tried setting PlayerName like this:
game.Players. “PlayerName”.Settings.Data.Ability.Value
game.Players.[“PlayerName”].Settings.Data.Ability.Value
game.Players[“PlayerName”].Settings.Data.Ability.Value
game.Players.PlayerName.Settings.Data.Ability.Value

I wanted the menu to display all the information I wrote in the script.


in lua if you wanna index with a variable you need to do the following:
game.Players[PlayerName].Settings.Data.Ability.Value

or
game:GetService("Players"):FindFirstChild(PlayerName).Settings.Data.Ability.Value


Hi,
Thanks with this but this script is causing this error I would be very grateful if you or anyone else could help me solve it.
CoreGui.Execution.22567:0 attept to index nil with 'Settings' CoreGui.Execution.18415:0 attept to index nil with 'Settings' CoreGui.Execution.8007:0 attept to index nil with 'Data'
The first and second errors were caused by the code:
game:GetService(“Players”):FindFirstChild(PlayerName).Settings.Data.Ability.Value.
And the third error was caused by the code:
game:GetService(“Players”):FindFirstChild(PlayerName).Data.Ability.Value.

it means it couldn't find the player and then you indexed it with "Settings" so you have to check if the player exists before continuing
